# In Windows XP Embedded how can you run Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-update, windows-xp-embedded

We distribute Kiosk software that runs on the Windows XP Embedded OS. The automatic Windows Update is disabled in XPe. What is the best way to go about keeping these kiosks up to date with Windows security fixes and things like that? The kiosks do have an internet connection to them.

Comment: This could be a question for ServerFault.com

Answer (score 2):

[**Windows XP Embedded Downloads and Updates**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/embedded/aa731258.aspx).

You may also be interested in this
short PDF [**Differences Between Windows XP Embedded and Windows XP Professional**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/2/71252520-2bb9-43c3-891b-bc09bfdde152/DifferencesBetweenWindowsXPEmbeddedandWindowsXPProfessional.pdf.)

---

Surprisingly, there appears to be no direct link on the [**Windows Embedded**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/wexpe/default.mspx) page